# What is the easiest way to extract the date and time from separate datetime values and join them together?

Tags: t-sql, sap-ase

I am currently dealing with a slightly strange  relation layout. The relation contains several fields, two of them, datetimeA and datetimeB are used to hold a datetime value.

I am not sure why it was set up this way, but **datetimeA** is used to store the **date** components with all of the time components being 00:00:00.0 while **datetimeB** is used to store the **time** component with all of the date components as 1970-01-01.

I am creating a simple reporting interface which uses this table and I need to extract the date from datetimeA, the time from datetimeB and join them into a new datetime. If possible I would like to make this happen in the query run against the database.

An ideal solution would be something similar to the [datepart](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks139.htm) function but with 'date' and 'time' parts.

Comment: I did look around for a while and didn't find one, but if there is a duplicate somewhere please point me to it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is SQL Server TSQL, but the date functions appear to be more or less the same in both products. I'm not sure how Sybase handles date literals so you might need to change them to get this example to work:

```
declare 
    @date datetime = '2013-02-15T00:00:00', 
    @time datetime = '1970-01-01T15:15:15'

select dateadd(ss, datediff(ss, '19700101', @time), @date)
```